# Проблемы перевода полей временной шкалы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, временная-шкала

Во [временной шкале вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4327/timeline/) отсутствует перевод слова "today":

> [image: today]

Так же и для хинта после смены формата:

> [image: хинт]

Перевод для [today](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263721?key=c5e7dfaf771d423ecf59b008369021e8) в transifex имеется, но в данном контексте, судя по всему, не используется.

Для участников с репутацией недостаточной для просмотра информации по распределению голосов "за" и "против" так же выводится непереведённое слово "Score":

> [image: score]

Не переведено Undelete

> [image: Undelete]

Не переведено Delete

> [image: Delete]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для [Undelete](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/68358910?key=0c4b04294bc78e7f1ecfa2502752366c), [Delete](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/68358916?key=7171e202622112e88ececaf6a3adffc6) и [Score](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/68358913?key=4f774552033a9242af0780e383784d29) перевод имелся, но не был утверждён. Должен стать доступен после подкачки transifex и новой сборки.

По `today` проблема [решена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290273/339911).